# Imprimir arquivo PDF usando PrintDocument

Tags: c#, impressora

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação, Console Application no Visual Studio 2015, que a função dela é imprimir documentos.

Eu consigo imprimir TXT e DOC sem problemas utilizando a class `PrintDocument` porém não consigo imprimir arquivos PDF. Existe alguma forma de imprimir um PDF com o `PrintDocument`?

```
     public void Imprimir(string caminhoImpressora)
    {
        streamToPrint = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\3013\Desktop\teste.txt");


        printFont = new Font("Arial", 10);
        var documento = new PrintDocument();
        documento.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = LocalizarImpressora(caminhoImpressora).ToString();
        documento.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
        documento.Print();

    }
```

Esse é o método que define o caminho da impressora que será usada e cria o objeto StreamReader do arquivo txt.
E o código abaixo é o evento que lê as linhas do arquivo e formata o texto:

```
   private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        float linesPerPage = 0;
        float yPos = 0;
        int count = 0;
        float leftMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Left;
        float topMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Top;
        string line = null;

        // Calculate the number of lines per page.
        linesPerPage = ev.MarginBounds.Height /
           printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics);

        // Print each line of the file.
        while (count < linesPerPage &&
           ((line = streamToPrint.ReadLine()) != null))
        {
            yPos = topMargin + (count *
               printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics));
            ev.Graphics.DrawString(line, printFont, Brushes.Black,
               leftMargin, yPos, new StringFormat());
            count++;
        }

        // If more lines exist, print another page.
        if (line != null)
            ev.HasMorePages = true;
        else
            ev.HasMorePages = false;
    }
```

Porém, ao tentar usar os mesmo métodos pra imprimir um pdf, consigo até imprimir, porém são código ilegíveis, como se ele não conseguisse ler o conteúdo do pdf em si.

Comment: O que acontece quando tenta imprimir um PDF? Aliás, coloque o código que você está usando. Não me parece ser um problema imprimir arquivos PDF com a `PrintDocument`

Comment: Então, eu uso um método que encontrei na internet, onde ele monta um StreamReader do arquivo, e meio que ele vai lendo linha por linha do arquivo, formata (muda fonte, posição na tela, etc) e depois efetua a impressão. Vou colocar o código abaixo.

Comment: Coloquei o código no post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não será possível imprimir PDFs utilizando esta rotina. Nela você está lendo, linha a linha, um arquivo texto e "desenhando", na mão, usando o `DrawString()` o conteúdo da linha em um contexto gráfico fornecido pelo `PrintDocument`. Um documento PDF não é uma coleção de linhas em texto, mas sim um documento complexo, binário (não textual), e repleto de construções de controle. É, praticamente, um programa em si só, que define a diagramação do que será extraído na tela.

Portanto, mesmo que seu PDF seja muito simples, ainda assim, se não for completamente padronizado, não será simples extrair o texto de dentro do mesmo.

O ideal é usar algum visor de PDF já instalado para abrir o documento e o usuário então o imprime, ou visualiza na tela, conforme lhe aprouver. Também é possível pedir a impressão direta do documento, o que pode ser mais interessante no seu caso. O código abaixo realiza isso de forma bem simples:

```
private static void ImprimeDocumento(string caminho) {
    Process process = new Process {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            Verb = "print",
            FileName = caminho,
        },
    };
    process.Start();
}
```

Contudo, em versões mais novas do Windows, como o 8 ou o 10, esse método não funciona mais, portanto teríamos que mudar o verbo para "open":

```
private static void AbreVisualizadorPadrao(string caminho) {
    Process process = new Process {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
            Verb = "open",
            FileName = caminho,
        },
    };
    process.Start();
}
```

Isso abrirá o leitor padrão do windows de PDF e permitirá que seja impresso por lá.

Se você quiser **gerar** o PDF manualmente e depois imprimir (usando o método acima), precisará de uma biblioteca de geração de PDF. Sugiro, fortemente, a biblioteca de código aberto [iTextSharp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

Se precisar mesmo exibir o PDF na sua aplicação e imprimir direto da mesma, o jeito será apelar para alguma biblioteca pronta (a maioria não é barata):

- http://www.o2sol.com/pdfview4net/overview.htm
- https://www.coolutils.com/TotalPDFPrinterX
- http://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/pdf-for-net-introduce.html

Comment: Isso não funciona em versões mais novas do Windows.

Comment: @jbueno se mudar para "open" o verbo ele abrirá o leitor embutido de PDF. Em versões mais novas do Windows, como o 10, abre o próprio Internet Explorer, e de lá pode ser impresso. Vou modificar o código com essa informação.

Comment: Perfeito, era exatamente isso que eu precisava. Muito obrigado!